# Get job status and type from BackupExec with use of PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, symantec, backupexec

I would like to get command, which could be executed on standalone hosts to get *status* and *type* of a specific backup job. Variable `$jobname` stores the name of the job.

```
Get-BEJob -Name $jobname | 
  select JobType, Status | 
  ft -auto
```

I also tried to use this one, but don't know exactly how to filter out necessary data.

```
Get-BETapeDriveDevice |
  Submit-BEInventoryJob |
  select Name, JobType |
  ft –auto
```

I would like to get only 2 words as output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What's the current output from the commands, and what does the output that you want look like?

Comment: @gvee : It shows the actual status, but I would like to get historical data, what was the result of a job execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain historical data, it looks like you need to use a different CmdLet...

```
Get-BEJobHistory
```

> **Description**
>
> Gets job histories in Backup Exec.
>
> Without parameters, Get-BEJobHistory gets all of the Backup Exec job histories. You can also specify a job history by job history name or job history ID (Guid) or pass a Backup Exec job history object through the pipeline to Get-BEJobHistory.

Source: http://systemmanager.ru/bemcli.en/index.html?page=topics%2Fget-bejob.html